# reactNativeNavigation.Navigation.startSingleApp is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm building a React Native app and using React Native Navigation to move between screens.  Something happened, some files were deleted and it seems like my xcode project settings were wiped.

When I boot up my app using 'npm run start' and 'react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhoneX", I get the following errors:

- red error simulator screen that says: _reactNative.Navigation.startSingleScreenApp is not a function
- the terminal window I ran "run-ios" fails and has this error: 
  `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNNCustomViewController", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I followed these instructions: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing

versions:

- node: v11.6.0
- npm: 6.5.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.55.3
- "react-native-navigation": "^2.2.5"

App.js:

```js
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

import AuthScreen from './src/screens/Auth/Auth';
import SequencesList from './src/screens/SequencesList/SequencesList';

Navigation.registerComponent("my-app.AuthScreen", () => AuthScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent("my-app.App", () => App);
Navigation.registerComponent("my-app.SequencesList", () => SequencesList);

Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
  screen: {
    screen: "my-app.SequencesList",
    title: "Sequences"
  }
});
```

AppDelegate.m

```m
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

@end
```

header search path has been set to: `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/ios`

Answer (score 4):

`setRoot({stack})` instead of `startSingleScreenApp(params)`

You are using a react-native-navigation version 2. check the API changelog

[Migration from v1](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/top-level-api-migration)

Comment: Thank you so much Harshal.  That was it  and it's now working